# SQL Query works in MS-Access but cannot implement it in vb.net form

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, ms-access

The block of code immediately following (given to me by a stackoverflow solver) works perfectly in MS-Access.  I'm trying to convert it to work in a vb.net form accessing the very same MS-Access database.  I get an error and cannot see my mistake.  Are there any vb.net coders that can see what I'm doing wrong.  The first block of code works in MS-Access and is the code I'm trying to convert.  And the second block of code is my conversion attempt.

```
SELECT at.animalID, amt.milestoneType
FROM
animals_Table at
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT animalID, milestoneType
    FROM animalMilestones_Table
    WHERE milestoneType = 'Intake'
) amt
    ON at.animalID = amt.animalID
```

Now, my conversion attempt:

```
dim selectAnimal as string
selectAnimal = "SELECT at.animalID, amt.milestoneType" & _
               " FROM animals_Table at" & _
               " LEFT JOIN" & _
               " (" & _ 
               " SELECT animalID, milestoneType" & _
               " FROM animalMilestones_Table" & _
               " WHERE milestoneType = '" & "Intake" & "'" & _
               " ) amt" & _
               " ON at.animalID = amt.animalID"
```

The error code I get is
!ErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that ACE.OLEDB doesn't like `at` as a table alias. Try this instead

```vb
Dim selectAnimal As String
selectAnimal = "SELECT atbl.animalID, amtbl.milestoneType" & _
               " FROM animals_Table atbl" & _
               " LEFT JOIN" & _
               " (" & _
               " SELECT animalID, milestoneType" & _
               " FROM animalMilestones_Table" & _
               " WHERE milestoneType = '" & "Intake" & "'" & _
               " ) AS amtbl" & _
               " ON atbl.animalID = amtbl.animalID"
```

Comment: Yay!!  You did it again Gord.  Works like a champ.  You're a genius.  Thank you.